# How do I add STM32F4 support to GDB client for watchpoints?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, gdb

I have been trying to debug my code and realized that my watchpoints for variable never execute.  When I looked into this problem online, I encountered similar situations and the response they received was their microcontroller may not be supported.  I have an STM32F4 and I am using GDB on Ubuntu with st-util.  Breakpoints currently work but watchpoints don't.  How can I add support for it?

Comment: Watch points should be supported with stlink and STM32F4. Have you tried using another GDB server, like OpenOCD?

Comment: Also note that the C/C++ code in question may have been optimized out or inlined, so the debugger was not able to find it. Try compiling with -Og -g3 which optimizes for debug and includes extra debug info.

Comment: @TonyK I haven't tried using OpenOCD.  I will make sure to try that.  I added both those options for compiling but with no prevail.  I also tried using st-util v2.

Comment: @TonyK Using OpenOCD seems to have worked.  If you make an answer I will be glad to accept it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that st-until has issue with setting watchpoints on STM32F4, even though it is supposed to be supported. As I previously noted, OpenOCD is an alternative and it looks like switching to it has resolved the issue for you.